# Facebook crawler with graph visulization

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api, web-crawler, information-retrieval, graph-visualization

our professor in the university gave us a bonus project subject about Information retrieval Systems, 
well he requested to make an app to enter the username of facebook  profile that have public access to his friends list and enter another user facebook profile 
and take the mutual friends between them , then visualize the output as graph visualization with their friends and connect the mutual friends together.

**My Question** 
what do I need to start this project like API and other things

we have a good knowledge in java and android 
if you know what are the things that we need to implement that 
like how we can communicate with facebook database and retrieve these information and so on.

Answer (score 0):

That project would only be possible by scraping profiles, which is not allowed on Facebook: https://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos_terms.php

That being said, your question is way too broad, this is your starting point to learn about the Graph API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs

Just be aware that you can´t get any data of any user without his authorization. And you can only get access to user friends who authorized your App too.

Answer (score 0):

That's a strange assignment, and your professor seemingly didn't either make himself familiar with the juridical side (as @luschn wrote), not with the technical side (becase there are already APIs for this use case, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/social-context/v2.5)